# The error that can't send and receive event in Kaa cluster

Tags: mongodb, mariadb, kaa

I deployed 3 Kaa clusters follow the kaa [Cluster setup guide](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/System-installation/Cluster-setup/) document.

The databases are MongoDB and MariaDB. When I run C Client(I make a  code change that every client can login in three kaa servers in random) firstly, it can login in kaa server and send or receive event.
But after I stop the Client  and start it secondly, it can not send or receive event.

Then I try to do it again and again. But almost it is bad. I will upload the [server log and the Client log](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=zh&nomobile=true#!topic/kaaproject/p6bauQRVnV8) .

The error maybe caused by kaa cluster. 
I generated a Java and Android Client SDK.The problem  would also take place while I run Java and Android Client .

Comment: The forum thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kaaproject/p6bauQRVnV8

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233984/the-bug-that-cant-send-and-receive-event-in-kaa-cluster

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The bug that can't send and receive event in Kaa cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233984/the-bug-that-cant-send-and-receive-event-in-kaa-cluster)